# How to "match" html hidden input with a chosen radio input in php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to `$_POST` the ID of the selected radio button. The problem is the value of my radio button is not the ID, but the string title.

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo '<input required type="radio" id="'.$product->ID.'" name="product" value="'.$product->post_title.'">';
    echo '<label for="'.$product->ID.'">'.$product->post_title.'</label><br>'; 
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="postid" value="'.$product->ID.'">';   
}
```

Is there a way I can "match" that hidden field,  so I can access the proper value in `$_POST`?
If I just do `$_POST["postid"]` it does not work because it just gets the last record from the `foreach` loop

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate IDs. Don't use the same ID for the radio button and the hidden input.

Comment: Thanks. Let me remove it!

Comment: Why don't you just change the radio button to have the product ID in the value? then you don't need the hidden input.

Comment: The hidden input shouldn't be in the loop. You only need one of them to hold the ID of the selected radio button. You'll need to use JavaScript to do that.

Comment: Because I'm required to particularly insert the string post_title to the db field

Comment: Is it possible to jam all the data in the `value` of the radio button as a json object? Then `json_decode` in php?

Comment: You already have the mapping between IDs and titles in the database, isn't that where `$products` came from? So when you're inserting the response into the DB, you can look up the title from the ID.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to put it all as JSON, but it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Querying `$products` is only to populate my list of radio buttons, which is 1 part of the entire `<form>`. I sql insert the form data to a separate table. I'm having trouble including the ID of the **chosen** product (1 radio button) to the form data being submitted

Comment: _"I sql insert the form data to a separate table."_ - so what, that doesn't mean that you could not query the product name based on the product ID first at this point. Which you should do, if you don't want me to be able to submit totally arbitrary product names. Your product #15 might have the name "Barbie Doll" in your product table - but if I manipulate the field value to "Funky Sex Robot" before I submit your form, that might lead to awkward situations, depending on what you do with the data later on ...

Answer (score 0):

Take the hidden input out of the loop, since you only need one of them in the form, not a separate one for each radio button.

```
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo '<input required type="radio" id="'.$product->ID.'" name="product" value="'.$product->post_title.'">';
    echo '<label for="'.$product->ID.'">'.$product->post_title.'</label><br>';  
} 
echo '<input type="hidden" id="productid" name="postid" value="'.$product->ID.'">';
```

Use JavaScript to copy the ID of the radio button to the hidden input.

```
const hidden_productid = document.querySelector("#productid");
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio'][name='product']").forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener("click", () => hidden_productid.value = button.id));
```